# show that $\lambda_{max}(B^{-1}A) \leq 1$ (eigenvalues, matrices, preconditioning)

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to get more familiar with eigenvalues and matrices but struggle to see the following:

> $\lambda_{max}(B^{-1}A) \leq 1$

$A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric, positive definite matrix
$B = (D+L)D^{-1}(D+R)$ with $D,R,L$ being the diagonal / upper right/left matrix if you diagonalize A (so called preconditioner if I remember right).
$\lambda_{max}(A) = \frac{\langle Ae_{max},e_{max}\rangle}{\langle e_{max},e_{max}\rangle}$, $\; \lambda_{i}$ eigenvalue, $\; e_{i}$ euclidean unit vector
$B = (DD^{-1}+LD^{-1})(D+R) = ID+IR+LDD^{-1}+LD^{-1}R = D+R+L+LD^{-1}R$

where $A = L + R + D$ thus $B = A + LD^{-1}R$, unfortunately we (or is it just me?) don't know if $A$ and $LD^{-1}R$ commute, so how can we access the eigenvalues here? Or is that the wrong path? I thought about how to gain the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}$. $\lambda_{i}(LD^{-1}R) = 1/d_{ii}$ obviously.

Thank you very much for every hint and thought :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $L=R^T$ and $B$ is invertible (indeed $D>0$ and $\det(D+L)=\det(D)>0$).

Assume that $x\not= 0$ and $B^{-1}Ax=\lambda x$, that is $Ax=\lambda Bx$. Assume that $\lambda\not= 1$;  then $Ax=\dfrac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}LD^{-1}L^Tx$. Now $x^TAx=\dfrac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}x^TLD^{-1}L^Tx>0$; moreover $signature(LD^{-1}L^T)=signature(D^{-1})=n\times +$; then $x^TLD^{-1}L^Tx>0$ and $\dfrac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}>0$; thus $\lambda\in (0,1)$.

Conclusion: $\lambda\in (0,1]$ and we are done.